# Twig embedding and field object

Tags: 8, theming

I'm using [Radix](https://www.drupal.org/project/radix) and trying to create a Botstrap carousel component with no luck.
This is the code so far. Kint shows me that media object is there with its multiple fields but nothing is rendered.

```
themes\custom\newtheme\templates\content\node--article--teaser.html.twig

{% embed '@newtheme/carousel/carousel.html.twig' with {'media': content.field_media } %}{% endembed %}


themes\custom\newtheme\src\components\carousel\carousel.html.twig

<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">

    {% for item in media.items %}
        <div{{ item.attributes.addClass(['field__item', 'carousel-item']) }}>{{ item.content }}</div>
    {% endfor %}

  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: The include path doesn't seem to match where the template actually lives?

Comment: That has to do with how Radix works. The code blocks get printed, only the loop is the problem. I can print `{{ media }}` alone and managed to print individual items with `{% for item in media %} {% if item['#theme'] is defined %}` but why `content.field_media.items` is different from `media.items`?

Comment: Try content.field_media[‘#items’]?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I achieved something similar was using:

```
{% for key, item in content.field_club_history if key|first != '#' %}
    {{ content.field_club_history['#items'][key].entity.field_games.value }}
{% endfor %}
```

The only difference is that **field_club_history** was EntityReference field to Paragraph of concrete type. Paragraph type then has fields like **field_games**. Try to use following code example and get fields from specific item that you need.

```
{{ content.field_club_history['#items'][key].my_field_name }}
```